# Array index(of:) method signature returns Int? but using said method returns Array.Index?

Tags: swift

In Apple's documentation, the `index(of:)` signature shows that the return type is an `Int?`:

> func index(of element: Element) -> Int?

However, in the following example `i` is of type `Array.Index?`

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

var i = arr.index(of: 4) // i is Array.Index?
```

Why is the return type different? Are they one and the same? What am I missing here?

Comment: `Array.Index` is `Int` ;)

Comment: Ah I see now. It's a typealias. But why?

Comment: Not too sure what you mean by why – `Collection` requires an `Index` `associatedtype`, `Array` satisfies this with `Int`.

Comment: @Aaron Because it would be unnecessarily restrictive for the `Collection` protocol to require its conforming types use `Int` for its indices. What if I want to use my own `Int128` to index collections larger than what `Int` (`Int64`) can index?

Comment: Ah, thanks guys. I get it now.

Comment: @Alexander More specifically, why should `Index` be a number at all? `Dictionaries` are collections, too!